# How to load two fields returned by a query into an associative array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a complex query with this structure:

```
SELECT DRIVER, TRAVEL 
FROM TRAVELS
WHERE ...
```

Returns something like this:

```
DAVID PARIS
DAVID OSLO
JHON  AMSTERDAM
DAVID MADRID
MARCO BARCELONA
JHON  ROME
```

Well, what I want to do is return the information in two parts. I mean, first of all an array of drivers which contains:

```
DAVID
JHON
MARCO
```

And according to the user's choice I want to get the travels of that driver. Assuming you choose *DAVID*, would return an array with:

```
PARIS
OSLO
MADRID
```

I know that I can do it easily separating it into two queries, but, as I said, is a complex query on a database with many records so in this way I'd save time.

I'm using **php**... how would you do this?, with an associative array?
Could you give me an example, please?

I hope I was clear in my explanation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: unfortunaltely, this is not give me this code site, you have to put effort into creating the function yourself, and if you get an error come here to ask about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both save them first in an array:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) { // for mysqli. for mysql use mysql_fetch_object($result)
   $travel[$row->DRIVER][] = $row->TRAVEL;
}
```

For the first:

```
$drivers = array_keys($travel);
```

For the second:

```
$locations = $travel[$driver];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it myself, but it looks like that [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) with some [`fetchAll` magic can do the trick](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-1022)

Or you can loop over returned results manually, filling whatever arrays you wish

Answer (score 0):

Just walk through the result with an array. If the name is not already in the array just add it with the name as the key and an empty array. Afterwards take the (name-)array and add the town and put it back into the array of all names. Than you have your associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the query as is and iterate through the result set and create data structure where array keys are the names of the driver and value is an array containing all the locations.

```
array("DAVID" => array("PARIS", "OSLO", "MADRID"), ...);
```

Now you can get list of drivers using array_keys function and you can get list of locations 
using `$arr["DAVID"]`

Comment: That is what I am already doing in my code...